# webapp2 CRUD routing returns 405

Tags: python, google-app-engine, url-routing, crud, webapp2

Hi since few weeks I'm playing with webapp2 and Python. For short I went into routing subject.
I found a helpful [link](http://www.geewax.org/friendly-url-routing-in-app-engine-with-webapp2/) that gives an idea how the routing can be done... Somehow in my project I'm struggling with this without any sight of success.

Basically all I want to do, is to add countries and then view each of them individually following the link /countries/country_id(where country id should be iso3) when they are created, being able to update their properties later with jquery xeditable or delete them. Better known as CRUD

Could I get any help here? It is probably a very silly solution... my brain is not getting it right... :-(

I keep getting this:

INFO     2015-04-06 15:33:49,839 module.py:737] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 405 187

Here is my handler code:

```
class HomePage(BaseRequestHandler):
      def get(self):
        self.render_template('index.html')

class CountriesHandler(BaseRequestHandler):
     def create(self):
    """I want to get this from https://github.com/mledoze/countries
       Could this be possible to get it from json...? to be researched
    """
        country_key = ndb.Key(Country, self.request.get('ccn3'))
        country = Country((country_key),
          name = self.request.get('name'),
          ccn3 = self.request.get('ccn3'),
          region = self.request.get('region'),
          )

        country.put()
       """I might be doing wrong here..."""
        self.redirect('/countries/country')

        self.render_template('add_country.html')

      def list(self, country_key):
        self.render_template('list.html')

      def view(self, country_key):
    """I think I have to do something here to get thinks to work with routing
    """
        self.render_template('country.html')

      def update(self, ndb_key):
        """This should update one single field"""
        if type(ndb_key) is ndb.key.Key:
          key = ndb_key
        else:
          key = ndb.Key(urlsafe=ndb_key)
        item = key.get()
        item.self.request.get('value')
        item.put()

      def delete(self, ndb_key):
        """This should delete an entity"""
        if type(ndb_key) is ndb.key.Key:
          key = ndb_key
        else:
          key = ndb.Key(urlsafe=ndb_key)
        key.delete()
```

Here is my router code:

```
"""Here i get always confused which one I should use and how I should use"""
    _route_info = [
      ('Main',   'GET', '/',                 HomePage, 'home'),
      ('country.list',   'GET', '/countries/',                 CountriesHandler, 'list'),
      ('country.create', None,  '/countries/create/',          CountriesHandler, 'create'),
      ('country.view',   'GET', '/countries/<id:\d+>/',        CountriesHandler, 'view'),
      ('country.delete', None,  '/countries/<id:\d+>/delete/', CountriesHandler, 'delete'),
      ('country.update', None,  '/countries/<id:\d+>/update/', CountriesHandler, 'update'),
    ]
```

**Update 1**:

I change the code a bit.
But still getting the same error:

```
class CountriesHandler(BaseRequestHandler):
  def create(self):
     if self.request.method == 'POST':
            country_key = ndb.Key(Country, self.request.get('ccn3'))
            country = Country((country_key),
              name = self.request.get('name'),
              ccn3 = self.request.get('ccn3'),
              region = self.request.get('region'),
              )

            country.put()
       return self.redirect(self.uri_for('country.view'))
     else:
      return self.render_template('putcountry.html')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the Route class. Like this:

```
_route_info = [
  webapp2.Route('/countries', CountriesHandler, name='country.list', methods=['GET'], handler_method='list')
]
```

Full docs [here](https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/routing.html)

Comment: Thanks, it helped me partially. The rest I got from here: [link](https://github.com/5aket/cpfthw/blob/master/webapp2/views.py)
 my code was missing the proper way to rout the entities.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting question because there is no builtin mapping. I chose ta map manually datastore IDs with country names and city names to implement url routing like `<country>/<city>/<category>` for my webapp. I ended up my yaml looking like to following to map the cities and countries.

```
includes:
- br.yaml # Brazil
- in.yaml # India
```

Then in `in.yaml`

```
handlers:
- url: /(india/for_sale|goa.*|delhi.*|gujarat.*|haryana.*|andaman.*|andhra_pradesh.*|arunachal_pradesh.*|uttar_pradesh.*|uttaranchal.*|tripura.*|tamil_nadu.*|sikkim.*|rajasthan.*|punjab.*|manipur.*|meghalaya.*|mizoram.*|nagaland.*|orissa.*|madhya_pradesh.*|kerala.*|karnataka.*|jharkhand.*|jammu_kashmir.*|himachal_pradesh.*|west_bengal.*|assam.*|bihar.*|chhattisgarh.*|maharashtra.*|pondicherry.*|lakshadweep.*|daman_diu.*|dadra.*|dadra_nagar_haveli.*|chandigarh.*|andaman_nicobar_islands.*|sindh.*)
  script: in.app

- url: /india/jobs.*
  script: india_jobs.application

- url: /india/cars-for_sale.*
  script: india_cars-for_sale.application

- url: /india/real_estate.*
  script: india_real_estate.application
```